# Exercício pegando a posição do array

Tags: javascript, lógica

Estou fazendo um exercício mas não consigo passar por todas as validações necessárias.

Escreva a função “medalhaDeAcordoComPosto(numero)”, que recebe um número como parâmetro, usando apenas um “if”.

Você tem que devolver a medalha que corresponde às primeiras posições de uma competição:

- medalhaDeAcordoComPosto (1) - "ouro"
- medalhaDeAcordoComPosto (2) - "prata"
- medalhaDeAcordoComPosto (3) - "bronze"
- medalhaDeAcordoComPosto (4) - "nada"
- medalhaDeAcordoComPosto (15) - "nada"
- medalhaDeAcordoComPosto (0) - "nada"

```js
var posicoes = ["nada", "ouro", "prata", "bronze"];

function medalhaDeAcordoComPosto(numero){
  return posicoes[numero];
}

console.log(medalhaDeAcordoComPosto(15));
```

A minha maior dúvida é como retornar "nada" quando eu passar parâmetro 0 ou maior que 3.

Comment: Na verdade, retorna undefined sim.

Comment: Criei um snippet com o código que você postou e ao executá-lo verá o retorno `undefined`, contradizendo o texto da sua pergunta. Com isso será necessário que você edite a pergunta e elabore um [mcve] que demonstre funcionando o comportamento que está descrevendo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ola @Raphael, me parece que seu exercício tem como objetivo fazer você entender duas coisas.

1. Que os índices tem seu inicio em `0`.
2. Identificar/Trabalhar com o tamanho de um `Array`.
   <sub>*[`Array.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)*</sub>

---

Vejo que o primeiro você já *matou*,
<sup>pois esta colocando como primeiro elemento de sua Array a string `"nada"`</sup>

Então para você terminar seu exercício basta você fazer a verificação (`if`) usando o tamanho da array ([`posicoes.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)).

Detalhe importante, `posicoes.length` é a quantidade de elementos na sua Array `posicoes`, **não é o índice do ultimo elemento**.
Sabendo disso basta você adicionar a checagem `if( numero >= posicoes.length ) return "nada";`

```js
var posicoes = ["nada", "ouro", "prata", "bronze"];

function medalhaDeAcordoComPosto(numero){
  if( numero >= posicoes.length ) return "nada";

  return posicoes[numero];
}

console.log(0,medalhaDeAcordoComPosto(0));
console.log(1,medalhaDeAcordoComPosto(1));
console.log(2,medalhaDeAcordoComPosto(2));
console.log(3,medalhaDeAcordoComPosto(3));
console.log(4,medalhaDeAcordoComPosto(4));
console.log(5,medalhaDeAcordoComPosto(5));
console.log(15,medalhaDeAcordoComPosto(15));
```

<sup>Obs.: Talvez seja necessário você adicionar no `if` uma checagem para números negativos, ficando +/- assim: `if( numero >= posicoes.length || numero < 0)`</sup>

---

### Agora vamos usar o índice `0`

Neste outro exemplo vamos criar um array só com os premios, então teremos:

```
var posicoes = ["ouro", "prata", "bronze"];
```

Na sua função vamos fazer o seguinte:

- Diminuir `1` no valor informado.
  <sup>Dessa forma se a pessoa chamar a função passando o `1` ele vai tratar como `0`.</sup>
- Fazer um `if` para verificar:

  - se o valor é **menor que** `0`, ou seja, índice negativo e invalido.
  - OU se o valor é **maior que** a *quantidade elementos na array* `- 1`, ou seja, o ultimo índice da array. `(posicoes.length-1)`

```js
var posicoes = ["ouro", "prata", "bronze"];

function medalhaDeAcordoComPosto(numero){
  numero -= 1;  /// ; isso é a msm coisa que `numero = numero - 1;`
  if( numero < 0 || numero > posicoes.length-1 ) return "nada";

  return posicoes[numero];
}

console.log(0,medalhaDeAcordoComPosto(0));
console.log(1,medalhaDeAcordoComPosto(1));
console.log(2,medalhaDeAcordoComPosto(2));
console.log(3,medalhaDeAcordoComPosto(3));
console.log(4,medalhaDeAcordoComPosto(4));
console.log(5,medalhaDeAcordoComPosto(5));
console.log(15,medalhaDeAcordoComPosto(15));
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda e excelente explicação, Icaro. Ainda não alcancei os 15 pontos de reputação, mas assim que conseguir vou dar +1 pela resposta

Answer (score 5):

A resposta do Icaro Martins está correta e responde perfeitamente a pergunta. Contudo, para quem tiver interesse, eu só queria acrescentar uma solução minimalista utilizando `||` e uma *arrow function*. Confira-se:

```
const medalhaDeAcordoComPosto = numero => posicoes[numero] || "nada";
```

Comment: Obrigado também, v. Santos. É uma solução bem enxuta, só preciso estudar mais sobre arrow function. Se tiver algum material disponibilizado, ficaria grato novamente :)

Comment: @RaphaelBarreto, não se preocupe se você não entendeu a síntaxe. Continue estudando o básico e quando você se sentir seguro com o básico ficará mais fácil para entender arrow functions. Indico o site da mozila: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions. Ah! A resposta do Icaro está muito boa, eu acho que você deveria aceitar ela.

Answer (score 3):

Segue minha solução para o problema:

```js
var posicoes = ['nada', 'ouro', 'prata', 'bronze'];

function medalhaDeAcordoComPosto(numero){
   if( numero >= posicoes.length ){
     return ("nada");
   } else{
     return posicoes[numero];    
   } 
  
}


console.log(medalhaDeAcordoComPosto(100));
```

Answer (score 2):

Olá, Raphael!

Então... A função que você criou retorna um elemento do array. Sendo assim, o (numero) da função deve ser um valor relacionado a posição de um elemento array.

Por exemplo, o valor "ouro" está na posição 1 do array. Sendo assim, se caso você quiser imprimir o elemento "ouro" na tela, você tem que colocar o código da seguinte forma:

```
var posicoes = ["nada", "ouro", "prata", "bronze"];

function medalhaDeAcordoComPosto(numero){
  return posicoes[numero];
}

console.log(medalhaDeAcordoComPosto(1));
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, Daniel. E já perguntando de novo, como eu faria caso eu digitasse um elemento fora do array? Por exemplo, se eu executar console.log(medalhaDeAcordoComPosto(4)) vai aparecer como undefined. Mas e se eu quiser retornar a opção "nada"?

Comment: Ai você teria que colocar o número da posição correspondente ao elemento "nada" que neste caso seria a posição 0. Então o console.log ficaria da seguinte forma:      console.log(medalhaDeAcordoComPosto(0));
Ou seja, apenas troquei o número 1 que correspondia a posição do elemento "ouro" e coloquei o 0 que corresponde a posição do elemento "nada". Caso tenha ficado alguma dúvida pode mandar outra pergunta sem problemas.

Answer (score 2):

mano, eu peguei a sua sabe por que eu justamente não sabia fazer o começo e trabalhei com if e else para tratar numeros <0 e >3 se liga:

```js
var medal = ["nada", "ouro", "prata", "bronze"];

function medalhaDeAcordoComPosto(num){
    if (num >3 || num <0){
    return medal[0];
  }
  else{
    return medal[num];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function medalhaDeAcordoComPosto(numero) {
  var medalhas = ['nada', 'ouro', 'prata', 'bronze', 'nada', 'nada']

  if(medalhas.indexOf(medalhas[numero]) == numero) {
    return medalhas[numero]
  } else {
    return medalhas[3, 4]
  }
}
```

Não sei se já conseguiu resolver, porém, segue resolução... (Espero ter ajudado)
Abraço!

Answer (score 1):

Segue uma solução executada com sucesso:

```
function medalhaDeAcordoComPosto(numero){

  var posto=["ouro","prata","bronze","nada"];

  var posicao=numero-1;

  if (numero ==0 || numero >= posto.length){
     posicao=3;
    return posto[posicao];
  } else{

  return posto[posicao];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu faria assim...

```
function medalhaDeAcordoComPosto(posto){
var medalhas = ["nada","ouro","prata","bronze"];
if((posto > 0) && (posto < 4)){
    return console.log(medalhas[posto]);
}else{
    return console.log(medalhas[0]);
}
```

}