# Ajuda em arrays em JS

Tags: javascript, array

Pessoal estou realizando um curso e não consigo passar desse exercicio.

Escreva a função “medalhaDeAcordoComPosto(numero)”, que recebe um número como parâmetro. Usando apenas o máximo de um “if” apenas. Talvez os arrays possam ser úteis aqui.

Você tem que devolver a medalha que corresponde às primeiras posições de uma competição:

medalhaDeAcordoComPosto (1)
"ouro"
 medalhaDeAcordoComPosto (2)
"prata"
 medalhaDeAcordoComPosto (3)
"bronze"
medalhaDeAcordoComPosto (4)
"nada"
 medalhaDeAcordoComPosto (5)
"nada"

```
function medalhaDeAcordoComPosto (numero){
    var medalhas = ["ouro","prata", "bronze"];
    numero= numero -1;
    if (medalhas[numero] = "undefined"){
        return "nada"
    }else{
        return medalhas[numero];
    }

}
```

Estou utilizando esse código, mas recebo um erro:
A função medalhaDeAcordoComPosto(1) deve retornar "ouro"
A função medalhaDeAcordoComPosto(2) deve retornar "prata"
A função medalhaDeAcordoComPosto(3) deve retornar "bronze"

Ao meu ver era pra dar certo, alguém poderia me ajudar a entender o que está errado nesse código?
Muito Obrigado.

Comment: Você está atribuindo um valor no `if` ao utilizar `=`, use `==` ou `===` para comparações

Comment: Inclusive, tem uma pergunta sobre esse exercício se você tiver outras dúvidas, dê uma olhada lá: [Exercício pegando a posição do array](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/422836/100416)

Comment: Então Rafael, coloquei o segundo=.
```
function medalhaDeAcordoComPosto (numero){
    var medalhas = ["ouro","prata", "bronze"];
    numero= numero -1;
    if (medalhas[numero] == "undefined"){
        return "nada"
    }else{
        return medalhas[numero];
    }

}
```
Mas agora aparecem outros erros:
A função medalhaDeAcordoComPosto(4) deve retornar "nada"
A função medalhaDeAcordoComPosto(45) deve retornar "nada"

Eu vi o seu código e entendi ele, mas eu queria entender o porque o meu está errado ainda, você poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

O erro está em:

```js
medalhas[numero] = "undefined"
```

Ao utilizar apenas um **=** ao invés de **==** você está atribuindo o valor a variável e não comparando.

Sugiro também verificar a função *indexOf*, que poderá ser útil na solução deste problema.